# Swift Debugging parameters

Tags: swift, xcode

When using Xcode and selecting predefined functions, how can you see what parameters they are expecting? For instance, `Void go(to: PDFPage)`. I am entering an 'int' in place of PDFPage and it isn't taking it.

[image: xCode Snippet]

Comment: You can see that it expects a parameter of type `PDFPage`, not an `int`. – May I suggest that you browse through ["Defining and Calling Functions"](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html) in the Swift language reference?

Answer (score 1):

`PDFPage` itself is a type and it is expecting in that type only. If it would be expecting `Int` instead of `PDFPage` there would be `Int` in the screenshot above.